# Boot problems in ubuntu 17.10 after I upgraded it from 14.04

Tags: boot, 17.10

I have a dell inspiron which I bought few months ago, it came with ubuntu 14.04, it was going well until I upgraded to 17.10, when I power on the system it boots up ask me to enter decrypt password I enter it, it shows me the ubuntu logo and then black screen, it does not put me into the login screen, then I manually power off the system with power button, I repeat these steps until I get the login screen, I get login screen after 4-5 reboots.

I installed a boot repair tool and logged my system info in the following link,

http://paste.ubuntu.com/26200594/

Comment: when you reach black screen press `ctrl+alt+f2` it will get you to tty2; login and debug; instead of rebooting maybe just restart display manager; see `ps aux | grep -i dm` might be gdm..

Comment: By black screen I mean nothings happening, not even ctrl+alt+del .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of R & D, I found a solution,
I updated linux kernel, previously it was 4.13 now its 4.15.
You can download latest kernel from the following link,

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

After downloading all the .deb files you can install it using,

sudo dpkg -i *.deb